# Duplicate a row 100 times in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to insert a row 100 times in a table based on count. For example, I have a table with `table_id`, `table_name` and want the rows

```
1,asd
2,asd
3,asd
4,asd
'
'
'
100,asd
```

I am looking for a solution using SQL Developer.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the same data so many times?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`connect by level`](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html) syntax to easily produce your result.

```
 select level, 'asd'
   from dual
connect by level <= 100
```

Or, as FSP notes an anonymous PL/SQL block with a loop, which isn't as good a solution as you should always use SQL over PL/SQL if possible...

```
begin

   for i in 1 .. 100 loop
      insert into my_table(table_id, table_name)
      values(i, 'asd');
   end loop;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle it can be done with a single stamtement:

```
insert into your_table (table_id, table_name) select level, 'asd' from dual connect by level <= 100;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO ICKD (ICKD_APLN_ID,ICKD_CHR_KY1_ID,ICKD_RUN_ID)
 select level, 'asd',1
   FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;


Using this I am receiving the following error

Comment: @user1442692, you have three columns defined and you're only inserting two.